# EC2 describe Images API takes a lot of time to return results

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am currently using the AWS CLI to perform a DescribeImages using the EC2 API. My exact command is as follows:

```
aws --region us-east-1 ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --filters "Name=virtualization-type,Values=hvm" "Name=architecture,Values=x86_64" "Name=name,Values=amzn-ami-hvm-2016*x86_64-gp2" --query 'Images[*].{ID:ImageId,Name:Name,CreationDate:CreationDate}'
```

I specifically checked this twice or thrice and it takes about 14 seconds for this API to return results to me. Is this common or known?

Comment: its slow for me too

Comment: It took longer for me! I would assume it takes a long time because 'amazon' owns a LOT of AMIs and filtering them takes time. I would recommend caching the results and only running this query occasionally to update the cached list.

Comment: As per 2020, the issue is still there!

Answer (score 4):

The response time depends on the specificty of your query.

If you limit the request's owners, executable users, image ids or filters you can bring the response time down accordingly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because the `describe-images` command didn't have paging. I reported the issue and after pinging the maintainers for ~2 years it finally got fixed :)

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/397